# SSRS footer item wont format correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am using SSRS with Visual Studio 2010. I have a cell pulling to a footer text box using the value:

```
=ReportItems!GuarantorBalance.Value
```

I CANNOT format the cell in the footer with the currency format. I tried every which way to format the text box but it never pulls the currency value. If I try to format the account number in the footer it will format with a currency value. Any ideas why the GuarantorBalance won't format with a currency value? Is there any other techniques I can try besides using the preset values in report designer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an explicit format for the value using an expression, like:

```
=FormatCurrency(ReportItems!GuarantorBalance.Value)
```